# How to retrieve data to display drop down list based on another selected value from the previous list in my PHP code

Tags: php, html, sql-server

I am facing difficulties while selecting values from drop down list based on the selected value from another drop down list that too retrieve from sql database

My PHP code is embedded with html, here is the code i am trying to do with select:

```
    Country Name:&emsp;<select name="status" style="width: 150px;">

    <option value="select_country" selected>select</option>

    <?php
    $c_id="";

    include 'dbconfig.php';

    $sql = "select * from Country";

    $result = sqlsrv_query($conn,$sql);

    while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result))
    {
      echo("<option value = '" . $row['Country'] . "'>" . $row['Country'] . "            </option>");

      $c_id=$row['CountryId'];
     }
    ?>

</select>&emsp;<a href="Create New Country.php">Create New Country</a>
<br /><br />


State Name:&emsp;<select name="status" style="width: 150px;" >
<option value="select_State" selected>select</option>
   <?php
     $s_id="";

     $sql = "select * from State where CountryId = $c_id";

     $result = sqlsrv_query($conn,$sql);

     while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result))
     {
       echo("<option value = '" . $row['State'] . "'>" . $row['State'] . " </option>");

      $c_id=$row['State'];
      }
     ?>
</select>&emsp;<a href="Create New State.php">Create New State</a>
```

Please suggest me how to overcome this and thanks in advance..

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 0):

You should use AJAX if you want the second select shown options based on the first option list picked value.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use JAAX upon selection of first drop down list and replace the options of second drop down list.